# Can I change the keycodes on a keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Lenovo notebook with a nonstandard keyboard layout in which there's a slash/question (/?) key next to the righthand Shift, that by br-abnt2 default was mapped to apostrophe/quote ('"). There's also a standard apostrophe/quote key next to 1. Yesterday I changed my br-abnt.map and my xorg layout files so as to fix the /? key. Then I realized the '" now was mapped to /?.

Today I tested these two keys with `xev` and they have the same keycode, so I can/t fix one without messing up the other.

Is it possible to change the keycodes on these keys so that they can be configured separatedly? How can I fix this?

EDIT: here's the `evtest` output for pressin first '" then /?:

`Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1525650895.009067, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1c
Event: time 1525650895.009067, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1525650895.009067, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1525650897.410587, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 29
Event: time 1525650897.410587, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 41 (KEY_GRAVE), value 1
Event: time 1525650897.410587, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
'Event: time 1525650897.466550, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 29
Event: time 1525650897.466550, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 41 (KEY_GRAVE), value 0
Event: time 1525650897.466550, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1525650908.301683, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 29
Event: time 1525650908.301683, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 41 (KEY_GRAVE), value 1
Event: time 1525650908.301683, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
'Event: time 1525650908.411541, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 29
Event: time 1525650908.411541, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 41 (KEY_GRAVE), value 0
Event: time 1525650908.411541, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------`

(the first SYN_REPORT is before I type either)

Comment: You may find [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1169558/21005) useful. It might be helpful, if you showed exactly how did you change the .map file and xorg layout file.

Comment: Does [this](https://yulistic.gitlab.io/2017/12/linux-keymapping-with-udev-hwdb/) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `evtest` to find out how the kernel sees them. If they have different scancodes, the kernel input layer can map them to different keycodes, for example using the [udev hwdb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes).

Comment: evtest gave me the same information as xev. they seem to have the same scancode. is there anything else to be done?

Comment: Please edit question with the `evtest` output for both keys, and indicate in which order you pressed them.